# spring without xml - 404 after deploying on tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat

Spring application configured without xml.

For doploying via IDEA on Tomcat - It's all working;

But if packaging via maven plagin to WAR

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>default-war</id>
         <phase>prepare-package</phase>
         <configuration>
            <warName>appName</warName>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

after deploying: Tomcat showing 404 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need add path to *webapp* directory to *configuration* section of plugin

```
<webappDirectory>src/main/webapp</webappDirectory>
```